# Apache server password file (htpasswd) encoding

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I use .htaccess, basic authentication and a corresponding password file to secure my web-space. The hosting is Linux / Apache.

I want to support a user name with French accents (ie. not ASCII).

- Are non-ASCII user names supported?
- What encoding should the password file be in (UTF8, Latin-1, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems basic authentication does not support any non-ASCII characters as detailed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702629)